# How can i download wiki part in one txt file

Tags: text, machine-learning, wikipedia, dump

I need a huge natural text file for machine learning and Wikipedia dump is great for this purpose. So how can i download several gb of text in some language (non-eng) without xml tags (just content)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Phase a:**

Go to dumps.wikimedia.org. Find a dump that fits your request. For machine learning - best way is to download "All pages, current versions only" dump of your language. Download and unzip it.

**Phase b:**

As the dump is xml file with a wiki-markup syntax of content - it has to be converted to plain text. The best solution i've found is to use this toolkit - https://github.com/yohasebe/wp2txt . It needs no much memory and works well.

**Phase c:**

wp2txt produces a hundreds of 10mb txt file, so we need to concatenate them. Use

```
cat * > all.txt
```

at nix systems or

```
cat dump.txt | sed 's/\W/ /g'
```

for windows one.

p.s. Also i've found better semi-legal solution for ML case. The solution is to download some huge txt-literature library. Have a nice learning!

Comment: if anyone has done that it would be great if you upload that somewhere, might be use to many people.

Answer (score 1):

You could grab a dump of all content of a Wikipedia of your choice from [dumps.wikimedia.org](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/backup-index-bydb.html). You will likely want one of the `*wiki-20160501-pages-articles.xml` files. Then, you could strip all XML tags from the dump using a tool like xmlstarlet:

```
xml sel -t -c "//text()" fywiki-20160501-pages-articles.xml > articles.txt
```

However, the text in a Wikipedia dump will be wiki markup, not natural text. You strip everything that's not alphanumeric with something like `sed`:

```
cat dump.txt | sed 's/\W/ /g'
```

This doesn't give you a clean corpus (for example, wikimarkup keywords and html entities will still be in your dump file) but it may be close enough for your purpose.

Comment: Xmlstarlet needs too much memory. Every time i've tried it it was fallen with out of memory exception. Using wp2txt instead.

Answer (score 0):

for Python try this after downloading .xml  dump

pip install wiki-dump-reader

https://pypi.org/project/wiki-dump-reader/